# Unable to change the brightness on my Dell XPS 15 (L502X)

Tags: laptop, dell, 13.04, brightness, xps

I am using ubuntu 13.04 and I am unable to change the brightness on my laptop and need a bit a help.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: @Seth I've got the same problem on my Dell XPS 17 L520X. It worked fine in 12.10, but is now broken in 13.04 (including `xbacklight -set 60`). My laptop uses an Nvidia optimus (I also use bumblebee). Neither of the following work for me: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=vendor"` in grub, and `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` in the Device section of `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` and `xorg.conf.nouveau`.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I've had a lot of graphics problems on 13.04 too. I'm currently waiting to see what happens before upgrading.

Comment: @Seth Do you mean that you've upgraded on one system already? I'm going to file a bug on the Bumblebee page (although I'm not sure if they are responsible for this bug), and I'll update here when I hear back.

Comment: @Sparhawk I've reinstalled with 13.04 twice and it never quite worked graphics wise, so I installed 12.10 and am now waiting.

Comment: On what computer? Using Bumblebee?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/801222/brightness-doesnt-change-on-dell-xps15-9550-with-16-04?rq=1).I was facing same issue and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

On my XPS 15, I got it working like this:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` with sudo permissions in your favourite text editor, e.g. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Go to the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and add  `acpi_backlight=vendor dell_laptop.backlight=0`  to whatever is between the quote marks, e.g. my line now looks like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor dell_laptop.backlight=0"`
3. Run `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot. Your brightness controls should now work.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround is to just set acpi to off  in grub (the advice given for the old kernel)" just set `acpi=off`  like in the older kernels. You lose clean shutdown and battery info, but this is more important for me now.