# Brightness doesn't change on Dell XPS15 9550 with 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dell, screen, brightness

If I try to change screen brightness on my Dell XPS15 with Fn + F11 or Fn + F12 or in the System Settings Dialogue, nothing happens. The bar indicating the screen brightness changes but the screen stays at a constant brightness, except when I turn the brightness off, the screen goes dark. I tried changing the grub settings as indicated here: [Unable to change the brightness on my Dell XPS 15 (L502X)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287589/unable-to-change-the-brightness-on-my-dell-xps-15-l502x), but that didn't change anything. Has anyone encountered this problem before and can tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same behaviour than you so hopefully this will solve your issue:

In a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> type acpi_listen and press alternatively the luminosity up and down keys <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> you should get and output similar to the one below.

```
alexisv@SlingBeast-XPS15:~$ acpi_listen
 PNP0C14:02 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
 PNP0C14:02 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
 PNP0C14:02 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
 PNP0C14:02 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
```

That tells us the BIOS is registering the key presses and forwarding them to the OS correctly.

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to exit from acpi_listen and type lspci, in my case I was looking for the Intel VGA chip PCI id.

```
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
```

Then still in the terminal type:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

The file didn't existed so I created it, paste into the newly created file the following content:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

The BusID section should match the "VGA compatible controller:..." ID retrieved previously with lspci. "00:02:0" becomes "PCI:0:2:0"

Save it, log out and restart.

That did for me. Creating the missing X config file got rid of the behaviour you described.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: @user1435514 what if at the first step I only get 
`PNP0C14:03 000000d0 00000000`?

Comment: it looks like the action regarding display control is not executed, sometimes there is a switch on laptops called FN to change behavior of the buttons, is it your case or you have single function button to control brightness?

Comment: While this worked for me, it broke steam which now reports "OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display". So I have to remove and add this file if I want to play games or a functioning backlight.