# Cannot control brightness on Dell XPS 15 9560 with Ubuntu 16.04 if prime-select nvidia

Tags: nvidia, dell, brightness, xps

laptop: Dell XPS 15 9560
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Graphic: Intel and Nvidia-396.54

When sudo prime-select intel, 
I CAN control brightness with keyboard and Brightness&Lock program after fixing from [Brightness doesn't change on Dell XPS15 9550 with 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801222/brightness-doesnt-change-on-dell-xps15-9550-with-16-04/833904#833904?newreg=316cb6b7e2e245cb81650bf9a2f85e96) .

However, when sudo prime-select nvidia,
I CANNOT control brightness with anyway.

Thanks,