# 19.10: Can't change brightness for XPS-15 7590

Tags: display, 19.10, xps

I'm having issues with my XPS-15 7590's brightness.  I can't change it using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11/12</kbd> keys.  I went through almost every solution indexed by Google and while I was able to solve this issue when I was on 18.04, I can't do the same with 19.10

I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801222/brightness-doesnt-change-on-dell-xps15-9550-with-16-04) method where I've added the following snippet to `etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

I've tried the following method but it also didn't work:

```
We first create two files that are triggered by the button presses. You need to create a file /etc/acpi/events/dell-brightness-up with the content

event=video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/dell-brightness.sh up
and a file /etc/acpi/events/dell-brightness-down with the content

event=video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/dell-brightness.sh down
```

I've also edited the grub file by adding `video.only_lcd=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.  Didn't work.