# Brightness doesn't change on Dell XPS15 7590 with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: dell, screen, brightness, intel, 19.10

If I try to change the brightness of my Dell XPs15 7590 with `Fn+F11` or `Fn+F12` nothing happens. The bar which is indicating the brightness changes up and down, but the screen stays on a constant brightness. I have tried the following:

- changing the grub settings as mentioned here: [Unable to change the brightness on my Dell XPS 15 (L502X)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287589/unable-to-change-the-brightness-on-my-dell-xps-15-l502x)
- adding an additional X config file like mentioned in [Brightness doesn't change on Dell XPS15 9550 with 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/833904/1016448).

The output of `acpi_listen` was:

```
someone@dell-XPS15:~$ acpi_listen
 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000 K
 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000 K
 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000 K
 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000 K
 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000 K
 9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000 K
```

The output of `lspci` was:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e20 (rev 0d)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0d)
```

And through this I created the following X config file:

```
someone@dell-XPS15:~$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

And after a reboot nothing changed.

Comment: For your 20-intel.conf file to take effect, it should reside in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d.

Comment: OK, should also work, but the preferred location is under /etc/. /usr/share/X11 is reserved for the distribution, and files there may eventually be overwritten by system updates.

Comment: Thanks that worked fine

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer if your issue is resolved. Config under /etc/ takes precedence over config under /usr/share. I therefore suspect that you already had a file configuring the Intel graphics under /etc/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OK, should also work, but the preferred location is under /etc/.
>   /usr/share/X11 is reserved for the distribution, and files there may
>   eventually be overwritten by system updates.

After putting the file there, I was able to configure the brightness of the screen.